# StopIteration error in nested foreach/for loop

Tags: r, doparallel, parallel-foreach

I've got a nasty error which only shows up when you ask R with `geterrmessage()` to actually display it. It also is no problem as long as you run the code in an interactive console session but when you call R non-interactively (in this case through a 3rd party software) this error results in the script being aborted.

Does anyone have an idea why the below code generates a (hidden) `StopIteration` error?

```
# Load the required packages
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)

# ----- set-up cluster for parallel processing -----
ncl <- max(2,floor(detectCores()*0.75)) #number of cores
clst <- makePSOCKcluster(n=ncl) #create cluster for R
registerDoParallel(cl = clst) #register cluster

# ----- display latest error  -----
print(geterrmessage())

# ----- run nested foreach/for loop and stop cluster afterwards -----
t <- foreach (j=1:8) %dopar% {
        for (i in j:8) {
            print(paste("j",j,"i",i))
        }
    }
stopCluster(clst)

# ----- display latest error  -----
print(geterrmessage())
```

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: I think that due to the way foreach is implemented, it will always throw a stopIteration when its done processing chunks, and although it handles that, by not complaining , yet it doesnt handle it in such a way that it wont be available to geterrmessage() to peek; you might try to file an issue with foreach to see if they can address that.

Comment: in the mean time, you should be able to fearlessly foreach by using function wrappers like purrr::safely to handle any error silently, and you can go through unpacking what was right and what was wrong after foreach ended, rather than check for a single global error message.

Comment: Thanks @NirGraham for your helpful comments! Not having experience with `purrr::safely` I was not able to apply the suggested workaround successfully so any hint would be highly appreciated but I already have a good starting point where to look so thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this black magic : .Internal(seterrmessage("")) idea sourced from stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-February/087931.html

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of using foreach, and proceeding despite errors, and logging them; here is an example of one possible approach

```
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(purrr) # for safely()

# ----- set-up cluster for parallel processing -----
ncl <- max(2,floor(detectCores()*0.75)) #number of cores
clst <- makePSOCKcluster(n=ncl) #create cluster for R
registerDoParallel(cl = clst) #register cluster


do_stuff <- function(j) {
  
  # bomb ; break on j = 6 
  if(j==6) stop("Bad News")
  make_string <- ""
  for (i in j:8) {
    make_string <- paste0(make_string,paste("j",j,"i",i))
  }
  make_string
}

do_stuff(8) # fine
do_stuff(6) #  error 

do_stuff_safely <- purrr::safely(do_stuff,"")

do_stuff_safely(8) # fine
do_stuff_safely(6) #  error 


# ----- run nested foreach/for loop and stop cluster afterwards -----
t <- foreach (j=1:8) %dopar% {
  do_stuff_safely(j)
}
stopCluster(clst)

# here you have a list of 8 coupled lists, result and error

(results <- lapply(t,\(x)x$result))  # <-- see how 6 is blank
(errors <- lapply(t,\(x)x$error))  # <-- see how 6  has an error recorded

# 
names(errors) <- seq_along(errors)
(any_error <- Filter(\(x)!is.null(x),x = errors) )
```

One can throw a try around the foreach itself to look for errors in foreach i.e. outside any single safe function call
example

```
t <- try(expr = {foreach (j=1:8) %dopar% {
  stop("Error in foreach itself")
  do_stuff_safely(j)
}})

inherits(t,"try-error")
```

try the above having having removed the stop() and t should no longer inherit from try-error

Comment: Thanks so much @NirGraham! But this catches any errors caused by a function inside the foreach loop yet it still produces a silent `StopIteration` error by `foreach` itself. So far I was not successful in trying to wrap the whole foreach loop with `purrr::safely` but I haven't given up yet... You think it's doable?

Comment: I think that due to the way foreach is implemented, it will always throw a stopIteration when its done processing chunks. you could put a single try() aroung foreach itself to catch if the overall foreach failed ?

Comment: I extended my answer at the bottom

Comment: Thanks, wrapping it with try and adding the `inherits(t,"try-error")` produces `FALSE`. I still get `StopIteration` though when calling `geterrmessage()`, so it still fails when called from that 3rd party S/W non-interactively. "Fun" fact: when building the parallelization with future.apply instead I also get a silent error (`all connections are in use`) and I will ask if it is any easier to avoid that one in a separate thread.

Comment: I dont think I follow yourfirst sentence. Are you saying that theres no inherits try error detection when there is a stop() in the code like in my example ?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to say that when I wrap it with `try` as per your example and run it and afterwards I paste the last line of code you suggested (`inherits(t,"try-error")`) the console output is `FALSE`. And, when pasting `geterrmessage()` thereafter I still get the `StopIteration` error so the 3rd party S/W will still stop.

Comment: oh, you need some sort of way to override geterrmessage ?

Comment: try this black magic : `.Internal(seterrmessage(""))` idea sourced from https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-February/087931.html

Comment: Sorry, had no time to test your "black magic" in the past weeks but now I finally found some time and it actually does seem to work! Placed at the right position in the code (i.e. directly after the foreach loop) it still allows for subsequent unrelated errors to be passed back, so you should make this an answer!