# Silent errors in parallelized R loops with future.apply (...and foreach)

Tags: r, silent, r-future

I need to build a parallelized loop in R which is called from an external 3rd party S/W which fails upon silent errors. I.e. what does not show up in an interactive R session and can only be made visible by calling `geterrmessage()` is an issue for me which I am seeking to avoid.

A parallelized loop via future_apply **sometimes** causes a silent error  `all connections are in use` (running the same code it sometimes is thrown and sometimes not). I've tried an alternative parallelization via `foreach` and it **always** produces a (different) silent error (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78029083/stopiteration-error-in-nested-foreach-for-loop)). Despite great help from the community I've also not found a general approach how to avoid any silent errors so I am wondering if there is maybe a future.apply specific approach to avoid that.
The only thing I could find about it is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73856910/all-connections-are-in-use-with-parallel-processing-on-aws/73858691#73858691) but I cannot derive a solution from there.

Below is a bit of code which has both the `foreach` and the `future.apply` example. Any idea why future_lapply sometimes throws that error or how to avoid it generally would be highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Mark

```
# Create a matrix
num_rows <- 100
num_cols <- 500
mat <- matrix(nrow = num_rows, ncol = num_cols)
for (i in 1:num_cols) {
    mat[, i] <- rnorm(num_rows)
  }

# Load the required packages
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(future.apply)

print(geterrmessage())

# ----- nested loop via future -----
plan(multisession)
tnew <- future_lapply(1:ncol(mat), function(j) {
    for (i in j:ncol(mat)) {
        print(paste("j",j,"i",i))
    }
})
print(geterrmessage())
plan(sequential)


# ----- nested loop via foreach -----
ncl <- max(2,floor(detectCores()*0.75)) #number of cores
clst <- makePSOCKcluster(n=ncl) #create cluster for R
registerDoParallel(cl = clst) #register cluster
t <- foreach (j=1:ncol(mat), .combine="c") %dopar% {
        for (i in j:ncol(mat)) {
            print(paste("j",j,"i",i))
        }
    }
print(geterrmessage())
stopCluster(cl=clst)
```

Comment: I don't want to make this an answer taking credit for other user's contributions but wanted to comment that the same solution which was suggested [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78029083/stopiteration-error-in-nested-foreach-for-loop) also works for the future based parallelized loop and btw also for other silent errors if that ever matters to anyone